# Passing null value to a CXF method (JAX-WS)

Tags: java, cxf

I have an interface containing the declaration of this method :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "foo")
public long[] foo(String params[]);
```

Right now if I call this method with 'param' containing null values they are ignored and only non null values are taken in account.
How can I pass null values? I heard of using 'nillable' within the 'XmlElement' annotation but it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance,
Marc.

Comment: how do you call this methid- foo(null)?

Comment: Hi limjohn, just like this : `String[] t={"a", "b", null}; long l[] = foo(t);`